# Best Jquery/Javascript practices for moving things off-page

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-animate, modal-dialog

Im wondering what the best practices are when displaying a div that wasn't there before, and then removing it when using Jquery. like a modal pop-up box like lightbox or the sort...

I have a pop-up shopping cart on my page and it works sort-of. Originally I had the shopping cart fade to 0. But if you do that, the html below is not clickable...So now I have moved the shopping cart div to the right really far and faded it. Then when you click the "cart" button, I reset all the styles back to normal again. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. say just to fade a div away, then disable the div so the html underneath is clickable...therefor you don't have to move the pop-up div around with a bunch of css.

heres my current code:

```
document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.left="2000px";

$(".open").click(function() {
$("#shopping-container").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast", function(){
    document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.position="relative";
    document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.top="150px";
 });
});

$(".close").click(function() {
$("#shopping-container").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast", function(){
    document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.position="absolute";
    document.getElementById("shopping-container").style.left="2000px";
 });
});
```

Comment: I always find it funny when I see people mixing jQuery and js like *getElementById*

Comment: so in all the instances were I would put document.getElementById("name").style...Would it be acceptable to just write $("#name").style...?

Comment: also, is there a way to write something like $("#name a li")? I tried but it didnt work that way...

Comment: @mike you should read up on jQuery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ its generally borrows from css selectors - so `$("#name a li")` would select all list-item elements which have a parent action-link element, where the action-link has a parent element with the name *name*

Comment: @Chris So are you saying $(#name a li") should work? cause doing it this way doesnt work at all for me...in jquery I can only use a class or a id, not a class or id + another element such as #name a or #name li etc.

Comment: @mike See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/nyqjQ/ if the example does work then there's probably something wrong with your jquery framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of moving off-screen, set style.display="none"

Answer (score 1):

Initially keep your div hidden...

```
<div id="shopping-container" style="display:none;">
......
Your elements here
......
</div>

$(".open").click(function() {
$("#shopping-container").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast", function(){
    $("shopping-container").show();
 });
});


$(".close").click(function() {
$("#shopping-container").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast", function(){
    $("shopping-container").hide();
 });
});
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey thanks Vipul! That is a really easy way to do what i need to do...thank you!!